# Create new if doesn't exist else update in firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase as database for my mobile app created using react native. In one scenario , i need to check that if the child already presented ? if not create a new child else update the existing child.

I have a tree named "CouponUsage", and it has all the users who used coupon code.

The structure of the tree is as follows:

```
   -CouponUsage
       -user1
          -coupon1: 0    // couponcode name and Number of times used
       -user2
          -coupon1: 2
          -coupon2: 0
```

So, what i want is, i need to check if "user1" or "user2" already existed ? And if they are not existed a new entry with "user1" or "user2" should be created with respective couponcode which they have entered.

The whole scenario is, user will enter couponcode in the app, and i am validating the code and then once correct, the coupon code will be sent to google cloud function, and then the above said thing will happen. So, that once the user entered coupon code ( every coupon code has separate user usage limit ), the code will be sent , and the function should check if the "user1" is already exist and if exist, the user entered code already exist ? And if that exist then just update the counter else create "user1" and add a child of "coupon1" ( coupon entered by user ) and then start the counter with 1.

Here is my code on google cloud function as of now ! :

```
 if(usersCouponUsage) {
            await admin.database().ref(`couponUsage/${phone}`)
            .update({ [couponCodeName]: usersCouponUsage + 1 });
        }
```

Its clearly updating the count, if i pass the count also. How to implement the above said in firebase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually quite easy. Since you are updating a counter, you should use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction), which while "modifying the existing value to a new value" will "ensure there are no conflicts with other clients writing to the same location at the same time."

The good news is that the transaction will automatically handle the case when the user/coupon pair does not exist.

Here is the code to include in your Cloud Function:

```
   .....
   const user = 'user1';  //Set the user
   const coupon = 'coupon1'  //Set the coupon

   const couponUsageRef = admin.database().ref('CouponUsage/' + user + '/' + coupon);

   return couponUsageRef.transaction(currentNbr => {
      return currentNbr + 1;
   });
   .....
```

---

If you want to test the transaction outside of a Cloud Function, just copy/paste the following code to an HTML file that you may save locally, change the Firebase config elements to your own ones and open it in a browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <script>

        var config = {
            apiKey: "--yourValue--",
            authDomain: "--yourValue--",
            databaseURL: "--yourValue--",
            projectId: "--yourValue--"
        };


        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var user = 'user1';
        var coupon = 'coupon2'
        var db = firebase.database();
        var couponUsageRef = db.ref('CouponUsage/' + user + '/' + coupon);

        couponUsageRef.transaction(function(currentNbr) {

           return currentNbr + 1;
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats currentNbr in this ? as the structure looks like "couponCodeName":"0",

Comment: `currentNbr` is just the variable that holds the current data stored at this location and that is passed to the function used as the `transactionUpdate` parameter of the Transaction. All of this is explained in the documentation I refer to in my answer. You can use any variable name and change it from `currentNbr` to `currentValue` or `xyz`for example.

Comment: Got it , if the user is not presented or coupon code is not presented under certain user. Will transaction create those automatically ?

Comment: Yes it will. I would suggest that you test it from the HTML code I've added to my answer. Just save it locally as an HTML file and play with it in a browser, changing the values of user and coupon and refreshing the browser. You will see that it covers all your needs.

Comment: I tried, it there isnt any error or any change.  I couldnt find whats wrong ? And, still i am unable to understand how it works, if there isnt any entry before. As we are incrementing, how it will increment if there isnt any value before ?

Comment: "how it will increment if there isnt any value before" -> it is just how the Transaction works. If e.g. `CouponUsage/user1/coupon1` has never been set, `currentNbr` will be `null` and then `currentNbr + 1` will return 1 and the transaction will set the value 1 at the reference `couponUsageRef` (i.e. `CouponUsage/user1/coupon1`), that's it... nothing rocket science! :-)  Which error do you encounter when trying/testing it??

Comment: I am not getting any error, like wise i am not getting the expected output, When there is not entry, and if i applied coupon code it simply skips the function. Nothing happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190245/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-dazzile-pro).

Comment: @DazzilePro Hello, did you have the time to look further at my answer?

Comment: Checking with your solution, will update within 24 hours !

Comment: @DazzilePro Hello, did you have the time to look further at my answer?